# How to refresh / reload an activity from Broadcast Receiver android

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver, start-activity

Hi guys how can I do to refresh an Activity from a class that extend BroadcastReceiver? Classical StartActivity with intent doesn't work. :/

Answer (score 0):

> Hi guys how can I do to refresh an Activity from a class that extend
>   BroadcastReceiver?

You can achieve this by adding a BroadcastReceiver in your Activity and send a broadcast to it in your class that extends BroadcastReceiver.

Register a BroadcastReceiver in your Activity:

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("yourpackagename.updateActivity");
registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // Update your Activity here.
    }
}, filter);
```

Send broadcast to that Activity in your class that extends BroadcastReceiver:

```
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if(meet the condition){
            Intent i = new Intent("yourpackagename.updateActivity");
            context.sendBroadcast(i);
        }
    }
```

PS. This solution can guarantee each Activity get an update notify when there are more than one Activity instance while the static field solution can't guarantee that.

Answer (score -1):

In Activity:

```
       class TestActivity extends Activity{
         private static TestActivity Obj;  

         public TestActivity(){
                Obj=this;
             }

         public static getInstance(){
           return Obj;
            }
         public void refresh(){
         //refresh Logic here
         }
       }
```

In Receiver:

```
        public TestReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
              ........ OnReceive(){


         if(TestActivity.getInstance()!=null){
            TestActivity.getInstance().refresh();
          }
          }
        }
```

Answer (score -3):

Add this line in your BroadcastReceiver

```
YourActivity.Update();
```

By this create a static Update() method in your activity class and do all the stuff you want in the Update() method.